# Drawing Polygons in maps

Tags: maps, geocoding, polygons

I have been trying to get this piece of code which is meant to draw a polygon of an area on my map but it is not appearing when I try to get it working coincided with my initial code which displays my map,which is at the bottom.I'm quite new to stack overflow so take it easy on me guys.

Below is the code I am trying to get working with my initial code, which is below..

```
function initialize() {
 var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

 var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.35720799587802, -6.306973099708557),


   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var africanPlains;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
  myOptions);

 var plainCoords = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.3571279554267, -6.311039328575134),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.35742570514506, -6.311720609664917),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.358523839347924, -6.310964226722717),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.35879916885124, -6.310363411903381)
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.358350957122745, -6.309478282928467),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.35821969422412, -6.309472918510437),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.3581076402103, -6.309118866920471),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.357460922716136, -6.308453679084778),
  new google.maps.LatLng(53.357150366768224, -6.310266852378845),

  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  africanPlains = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: "#FF0000",
fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  africanPlains.setMap(map);

  // add an event listener
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 });

}
```

Initial code:....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.35720799587802, -6.306973099708557),
      zoom: 16,

      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.35720799587802, -6.306973099708557),
      zoom: 16,
disableDefaultUI: true
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do you mind linking in jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/